# How to uninstall RubyMine 5.4.3.2.1?

Tags: 12.04, uninstall, ruby

I was trying to upgrade from RubyMine 5.4.3.2.1 to 6 for that I was trying to uninstall RubyMine 5.4.3.2.1. I removed RubyMine directory from where I installed RubyMine. Now everytime I need to run RubyMine version 6 from the .sh file given in RubyMine 6. How to completely remove the RubyMine and do a fresh installation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to delete following folder

```
rm -rf ~/.PRODUCTVERSION
```

~ is an alias for the home directory, for example /home/john

PRODUCT would be one of the following:

```
IntelliJIdea (IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition)
IdeaIC (IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition)
RubyMine
WebIde (WebStrom and PhpStorm use this common directory)
PyCharm
```

so in your case

```
rm -rf ~/.RubyMine5.4.3.2.1
```

you can read [this link](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108) for further knowledge

After that you also need to delete

```
rm -rf /home/USERNAME/.gnome/apps/jetbrains-rubymine.desktop (or /home/USERNAME/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-rubymine.desktop)
```

if previously installed rubymine apps, you also delete this

```
rm -rf /home/USERNAME/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```